# react native app auth - How to make scopes as optional?

Tags: react-native, oauth-2.0

I am trying to implement OAuth into my react native app.
I am using react native app auth.

I would like to make scope as optional.

Currently, it is mandatory.
How do I do that?

Can I modify the code of react native app auth and build it and import into my Example code?

- React Native app auth - [Github Link](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/react-native-app-auth)

Answer (score 1):

One of the maintainers of `react-native-app-auth` here.

Up until this moment I was under the impression that the `scope` parameter was a required paramater in the OAuth 2.0 request spec, but looking at the [relevant spec definition](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-3.3), it appears to be optional.

You should be able to remove the `array.length` check in the [`validateScopes`](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/react-native-app-auth/blob/master/index.js#L6-L7) helper. You can try this by editing the `index.js` file in your app's `node_modules/react-native-app-auth/` directory.

Once done, you can pass an empty array `[]` as scopes.
I'm not sure how the underlying AppAuth native libraries deal with it, but if it works, you can open a PR to `react-native-app-auth` and I'm happy to accept the change.